# Prevent 'darkgrid' ax2 gridlines in twinx() plot from disecting ax1 curve

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn, jupyter

I am having a problem with preventing grid lines in 'darkgrid' from disecting a line associated with the X1 axis when plotting a twinx() plot. I can "fix" the problem by not using 'darkgrid' or by passing an empty list to X2 (and lose the axis labels to - se last line), but I do want 'darkgrid' and x2 axis labels.

```
#Some imports
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style("darkgrid")
%matplotlib inline

#Data
d = np.arange(0, 1000, 100)
x1 = d/30         #redmodel
x2 = np.sqrt(d)   #bluemodel

#Figure
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (8, 12))

sy1 = 'r-'        #redmodel
sy2 = 'b-'        #bluemodel

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax1.twiny()

_ = ax1.plot(x1, d, sy1)
_ = ax1.set_ylabel('D')
_ = ax1.set_ylim(0, 1000)
_ = ax1.set_xlabel('X1')
_ = ax1.set_xlim(0, 31)

_ = ax2.plot(x2, d, sy2)
_ = ax2.set_xlabel('X2')
_ = ax2.set_xlim(0, 31)
#_ = ax2.set_xticks([]) #Empty list passed to omit_xticks, otherwise ax2 gridines disect red line
```

As I was looking for solutions to this problem I stumbled upon the *axes_grid1 toolkit* collection of helper classes which has the twin() option (in addition to twinx and twiny) which may be the solution to my problem. But if you know of a simpler one please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intent of your question is to answer as the challenge is to draw the grid lines of the x2 axis across the red line. I think you can simply set a standard for the grid lines of the x2 axis.

```
_ = ax2.grid(which='major', axis='x', zorder=1.0)
```

[image]

Comment: I am confused. You may have misunderstood my poorly worded question @r-beginners. The challenge is to prevent the grid lines from di-secting the red line. Your fig is correct however, the red line is not segmented. But adding the line you provide to my code has no effect. My red line is still segmented by the vertical (x2) grid lines.

Comment: Is your understanding of the issue correct, but the code I presented still doesn't improve it, or are you using the latest version of MPL?

Comment: Ah yes, right you are, update from 3.3.1 to 3.3.4 and all is well. A suitably embarrassed @bjarg thanks you @ r-beginners.